# Should I use a single script on multiple buttons in unity, or create a script for each button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working with Unity and need some help from an experienced user. If I have 2 buttons, should I use 2 scripts (one for each button) or just one for both buttons?  How does this apply on a larger scale with multiple buttons?

Answer (score 3):

It depends where the button is present. Usually, buttons are grouped in a panel. For example, there are pause menu panel with buttons(such as save, restart game buttons) and settings menu with buttons. You group these buttons other UI object under a panel based on their actions and when they should be visible.

You do not need a new script for each button. *You need a new script for each scene or menu panel.* So, each scene, menu or panel may have a script that handles their buttons.

You can have public button variables then use the `onClick` event to subscribe to their click events for buttons that are on the-same panel or menu.

You can either add a function for each button:

```
public Button button1;
public Button button2;
public Button button3;
public Button button4;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack1());
    button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack2());
    button3.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack3());
    button4.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack4());
}

private void buttonCallBack1() { }

private void buttonCallBack2() { }

private void buttonCallBack3() { }

private void buttonCallBack4() { }
```

Or use one function then for all of them then use an `if` statement to handle each individual button. If the Buttons are the-same Panel, I usually use one function to group and handle their clicks as below:

```
public Button button1;
public Button button2;
public Button button3;
public Button button4;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button1));
    button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button2));
    button3.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button3));
    button4.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button4));
}


private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
{
    if (buttonPressed == button1)
    {
        //Your code for button 1
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + button1.name);
    }

    if (buttonPressed == button2)
    {
        //Your code for button 2
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + button2.name);
    }

    if (buttonPressed == button3)
    {
        //Your code for button 3
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + button3.name);
    }


    if (buttonPressed == button4)
    {
        //Your code for button 4
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + button4.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need named functions either. `onClick.AddListener(() => { /*code here*/ } );` Programmer just used this as a wrapper around a named function, but using the delegate directly works too.

Answer (score 0):

Would you rather hard-code the functionality of each button? Make separate scripts.

Would you rather code a single general-purpose script for all buttons? Make one script that you can edit from the [Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html). (if they all do generally the same thing, this is probably the better option)

See [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) for the latter.